# AjaxControlToolKit HTMLEditorExtender adding anchor tag as a normal text when a link is added

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I am unable to write a nice title to this topic because my problem is a little weird. I am using AjaxControlToolkit HTMLEditorExtender in my website to send HTML formatted emails. Every other feature like bold, italic, underline etc. are working fine but when I add a link it shows the HTML code of it as follows:

[image]

As you can see **BOLD** is working but the anchor tag is appearing in HTML code format.

Code for extender and the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="376px" 
                TextMode="MultiLine" Width="795px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp2:HtmlEditorExtender ID="TextBox2_HtmlEditorExtender" 
    runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox2">
</asp2:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Can any one please tell me why this is happening? Is this some bug with the extender?

Comment: How are you assigning the HTML code to the `TextBox`/`HtmlEditorExtender`?

Comment: That is done by the HtmlEditorExtender automatically.

Comment: I may not have worded my question properly - can you explain the steps taken to reproduce the issue you're having? Is the HTML prepared and assigned programmatically? Is the user typing text and using the toolbar buttons?

Comment: @ShivaPareek - Please share the code which accepts value from HtmlEditoerExtender control to send email. I don't think the issue is with HtmlEditorExtender.

Answer (score 1):

Considering I do not have enough reputation for commenting on the post, I will ask a followup question here. Is there any way we could see the text you are getting on your C# backend? This is a possible source for the issue if the string has some weird formatting.

Plus email clients are not meant to be browsers and there is a possibility that the email client will not render the html correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Is that image a screen shot of the editor itself?  I created my own test project using your same code.

Also, how did you create the link?  I typed some text highlighted the text and clicked on the 'create link' icon and from there I typed in the URL.  It created the link as expected.

The only difference is that I didn't bother implementing a sanitizer, which it appears you did.  I would try disabling the sanitizer (just for testing purposes) and see if that's where your problem lies.

Comment: No its not the editor screen shot. Its the screen shot of the email. I was using sanitizer, as you suggested I removed it but still no difference.

Comment: @ShivaPareek Did you mean the email when opened from the email software show's the anchor as HTML markup? Does it show link correctly while composing the email itself in the HTMEditorExtender?

Comment: okay, so does it show correctly in the editor.  Also, how are you sending the email?  are you enabling html when sending the email?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should solve your issue-

```
txtEmialMsg.Text=Server.HtmlDecode(ActualStringFromExtender.ToString());
```

Or if you are getting (A href) text then you need to use following when sending emails

```
Server.UrlDecode(link)
```